# Doing a linear fit for each group of a data frame, check heteroscedasticity

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply, lm

I have a data frame like this:

```
ORD   exp type         mu
1   Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.15637365
2   Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.12817901
3   Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.13392221
4   Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.09683254
5   Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.11249738
6   Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.10878719
7   Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.11019295
8   Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.12100511
9   Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.09803942
10  Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.13842086
11  Combi pH=7 exp_F   mu 0.12778964
12     ORD0793 exp_F   mu 0.13910441
13     ORD0793 exp_F   mu 0.12603702
14     ORD0793 exp_F   mu 0.12670842
15     ORD0795 exp_F   mu 0.12982122
16     ORD0795 exp_F   mu 0.13648100
17     ORD0795 exp_F   mu 0.13593685
18     ORD0799 exp_F   mu 0.13906691
continues...
```

I would like to do a linear adjust like `lm(mu~ORD, data=df)` but for each group of type and exp. I have tried the following but its not working..:

```
intsl <- df %>% group_by(exp,type) %>% 
  fortify(lm(mu~ORD)) %>% 
  select(exp,type, .fitted, .resid)
```

I need to use fortify because I need .fitted and .resid fields to later on do a multiplot sorting plots by type and exp using `facet_grid` contained in ggplot in order to check if there's heteroscedasticity in each fitted model.. like but in an orgnanized multiplot:
[image]

Any suggestions? :<

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll directly answer your issue (thus why I'm not posting an answer) but I've found that the `modelr` package makes a lot of regression tasks so much easier.

Comment: In addition to the answer below suggesting `broom::augment`, it sounds like all you need is to add `+facet_grid(type ~exp)` to your ggplot call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `fortify()` in the `ggplot2` package says that the method will be deprecated and that the `broom` package should be used instead. Based on the info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html), you should do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

intsl <- df %>%
  group_by(exp, type) %>%
  do(fit = lm(mu ~ ORD, .)

intsl %>% augment(fit)
```

This should give you the data frame with the variables you used to group your regressions, the regression variables, and the extra output for each observation such as `.fitted` and `.resid`, so you can move on to plot them with `ggplot` directly.